# Running wordpress with one of php frameworks

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to run wordpress as a sub url of a website (for example /blog) as the other urls are under control of a framework (like laravel or codeigniter) ? And if yes how?

PS: I don't want to use a different subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , You can use , Simple put folder named as blog in root and install wordpress in that folder , if you are using laravel then you must create folder inside public folder and then install wordpress in that folder

for example

this is my domain at which i am using wordpress
https://www.coodingdessign.com/

this is another url at which core php are running

https://www.coodingdessign.com/php-editor/